# Empty POST request from HTML form (Python)

Tags: python, html, forms, post, basehttpserver

I am trying to receive POST requests in Python using the BaseHTTPRequestHandler module. I wrote a simple HTML form:

```html
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="http://localhost:8080/" method='post'>
        <strong>Access point</strong><br>
        <label for='ssid'>SSID: </label>
          <input type='text' id=ssid><br>
        <label for='passphrase'>Passphrase: </label>
          <input type='password' id=passphrase><br>
        <br>
        <strong>Calendar</strong><br>
        <label for='id'>ID: </label>
          <input type='text' id=calid><br>
        <br>
        <input type='submit'>
        <input type='reset'>
      </form>
    </body>
  <html>
```

and an minimal application:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socketserver
import socket
import sys

class ConfigHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        with open("index.html", "rb") as f:
            self.wfile.write(f.read())

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.headers)

        content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))
        config_string = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("UTF-8")
        print("Content length: ", content_length)
        print("Config string: [ ", config_string, " ]")

        self._set_headers()
        return

ConfigHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.0"
httpd = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", 8080), ConfigHTTPRequestHandler)

sa = httpd.socket.getsockname()
print("Serving HTTP on", sa[0], "port", sa[1], "...")
try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nKeyboard interrupt received, exiting.")
    httpd.server_close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The problem is that the every POST request are empty. I get content_length = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide **name** attribute to your form elements and see if it works.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/" method='post'>
            <strong>Access point</strong><br>
            <label for='ssid'>SSID: </label>
            <input type='text' id="ssid" name="ssid"><br>
            <label for='passphrase'>Passphrase: </label>
            <input type='password' id="passphrase" name="passphrase"><br>
            <br>
            <strong>Calendar</strong><br>
            <label for='id'>ID: </label>
            <input type='text' id="calid" name="calid"><br>
            <br>
            <input type='submit'>
            <input type='reset'>
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to elaborate on user7883492's answer.

According to [this protocol description](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13) only "successful controls" of the form are submitted.
According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) a successful control requires to have a name attribute.

Your controls fulfilled all the requirements to be considered a "successful control", except for the name attribute requirement.
This is the reason they were not submitted.
After adding the name attribute they became "successful controls", and were submitted.